# Please help on generating a unique sequence number using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: 1]

Please can someone help me with this?

I want to assign a unique sequence number based on the cost which is there in the unit cost column. I tried row number partition by but no luck.

Comment: please share to your sql query

Answer (score 2):

you need to use dense_rank():

```
select * , dense_rank() over (partition by Vendor order by unitCost) as seq
from table
```